# How to include grouping variable in the groupby().diff() results

Tags: python, pandas

Newby to pandas here so go easy on me.

I have a dataframe with lots of columns. I want to do something like

```
df.groupby('row').diff()
```

However, the result of the `groupby` don't include the `row` column.

How do I include the `row` column in the `groupby` results.

Alternatively, is it possible to merge the groupby results in the dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `index` by `row` column first:

```
df1 = df.set_index('row').groupby('row').diff().reset_index()
```

Or:

```
df1 = df.set_index('row').groupby(level=0).diff().reset_index()
```

Comment: Thank you! df1 = df.set_index('row').groupby(level=0).diff().reset_index() - this worked

Answer (score 0):

You could use `agg` with `np.diff`:

```
df.groupby('row').agg(np.diff)
```